# что делает данный код? page.url.indexOf('/edit_profile_country') != -1

Tags: jquery

Типо читается код, только как подгрузится url?
 `page.url.indexOf('/edit_profile_country') != -1` ?

```
if (**page.url.indexOf('/edit_profile_country') != -1**) {

   var countrySeachBar = myApp.searchbar('.searchbar', {
        searchList: '.country-search-block',
        searchIn: '.item-title',
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        if ($('.item-content.checked').length) {
            console.log('123123');
        }
    }, 350);
}
```

Comment: типо проверяет содержит ли свойство `url` объекта `page` подстроку `/edit_profile_country`

Comment: indexOf рассматривается в любом нормальном учебнике js